# If $N=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ then $N$ cannot be a prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem says that if $N$ can be expressed in two ways as the sum of two squares then $N$ is not prime. Clearly the first idea is to try and express $N$ as a product of two expressions containing $a,b,c,d$ but I don't see how.

Comment: Are you familiar with Gaussian integers?

Comment: What number theory do you know? (And it is *not* clear that you should try to prove directly that $N$ is composite.)

Comment: Or properties of the ring of integers modulo a prime?

Comment: I am not familiar with Gaussian integers. My number theory knowledge is not extensive. But I don't think that this problem requires advanced knowledge because this is supposed to be a high school Olympiad problem. I tried something with quadratic residues but it did not help.

Comment: yes I am familiar with the ring of integers modulo a prime.

Comment: https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CEQQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rowan.edu%2Fcolleges%2Fcsm%2Fdepartments%2Fmath%2Ffacultystaff%2Fosler%2F110%2520SUM%2520OF%2520TWO%2520SQUARES%2520IN%2520MORE%2520THAN%2520ONE%2520WAY%2520MACE%2520Small%2520changes%2520Oct%252008%2520%2520Submission.pdf&ei=x3nMVOu5Eoz08QXv2YDoCQ&usg=AFQjCNG6chU4eWAMpuF7QcQfYQyTcsZFEg&bvm=bv.85076809,d.dGc

Comment: [Euler's factorization wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_factorization_method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Suppose that $a^2+b^2=p$ and $c^2+d^2=p$ where $a,b,c,d$ are  positive.

Then $(ab^{-1})^2\equiv (cd^{-1})^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. The congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has at most two solutions, and they are mutually inverse. So by if necessary interchanging the roles of $c$ and $d$, we can assume that $ab^{-1}\equiv cd^{-1}\pmod{p}$. It follows that
$$ad\equiv bc\pmod{p}.$$

Note that $a,b,c,d$ are each less than $\sqrt{p}$. Thus $ad=bc$. But $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so $a$ divides $c$. Similarly, $c$ divides $a$ and we are finished.